# Thread cannot read and write streams on the same socket at the same time?

Tags: java

Code with lines commented-out works, code with those lines does not.....why? and how do I fix it?  (note: roughly same code running on the other end)

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream);
            //ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                //System.out.println( ois.readUTF());
                oos.writeUTF("hey");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

Edit:
Made some code to make it clearer what I'm getting at, yes its a little messy. (regardless of there being two sockets or not it doesn't seem to work):

Server.java (main):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6666);
        ServerSocket server2 = new ServerSocket(6667);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        Socket socket1 = server2.accept();
        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket1.getInputStream());
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("server reading");
            System.out.println( ois.readUTF());
            System.out.println("server writing");
            oos.writeUTF("hey");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Client.java (main)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6666);
    Socket socket1 = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6667);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream());
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("client writing");
        oos.writeUTF("yo");
        System.out.println("client reading");
        System.out.println( ois.readUTF() );
    }
}
```

### Output

Server:

```
server reading
```

Client:

```
client writing
client reading
```

Comment: i don't think you can do this on same port at a time

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you have an exeption, do you fail to send/receive data?

Comment: @nuda what exactly doesn't work? if you run the same (uncommented) code on the other end, you end up with a deadlock where both ends keep on waiting for each other to send something

Comment: @Deadpool why not, what's the problem with doing this on the same port at a time?

Comment: @mangusta added some code to the post, one end starts off reading while the other writes. It looks like the writer writes and moves onto reading but the reader never reads.

Answer (score 1):

.flush() your output streams. In my examples after writing on the output stream I have:

```
oos.flush();
```

I should have always flushed when I wanted to be sure the message was sent.